# How to convert DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame.

```
id   actions
1   [{"action_type":"link_click","value":"1","1d_click":"1","7d_click":"1"},{"action_type":"page_engagement","value":"2","1d_click":"2","7d_click":"2"}]
2   [{"action_type":"link_click","value":"2","1d_click":"2","7d_click":"2"},{"action_type":"page_engagement","value":"2","1d_click":"2","7d_click":"2"}]
```

I have to convert like this.

```
id    action_type       value
1     link_click        1
1     page_engagement   2
2     link_click        2
2     page_engagement   2
```

Is this possible with pandas? If so, how can I manage to do it?

Comment: I tried pd.json_normalize
and pd.concat([df.drop(['actions'], axis=1), df['actions'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
but i cant get example like upper side.

Comment: In your data, you have other values too. So you don't need all the other values except your expected output?

Comment: Yes. I need only 'actions_type' and 'value'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame((df := df.apply(lambda s: list(map(lambda t: [t['action_type'], t["value"]], s[1])), axis=1).explode()).to_list() , index= df.index)
```

if your `actions` column is `str`:

```
import ast
pd.DataFrame((df := df.apply(lambda s: list(map(lambda t: [t['action_type'], t["value"]], ast.literal_eval(s[1]))), axis=1).explode()).to_list() , index= df.index)
```